# save value to custom field added to spy_sales_payment table spryker

Tags: spryker

I have added a custom field called custom_payment_id in spy_sales_payment table,added the field in transfer file too
sales_payment.transfer.xml

and added the column using slaes.schema.xml file

How to set value to this field while placing order

Comment: Depends on your implementation. Usually the mapping is done in you business or persistence layer. Hard to tell without code, but if your transfer field name matches the database field name, you can be lucky and have to do nothing since the transfers/entities are translated to each other using fromArray/toArray

Answer (score 0):

A concrete answer is hard, because it depends where you get the data from. Spryker is very flexible and there are many ways to solve that.

I guess you're adding the `custom_payment_id` during checkout (i.e. in the payment step) to the `PaymentTransfer` object inside of the `QuoteTransfer` object. (It's a good idea to extend the PaymentTransfer object as well).

Then `\Spryker\Zed\Payment\Business\Order\SalesPaymentSaver::mapSalesPaymentEntity` is a good starting point to extend, which hydrates the `SpySalesPayment` object from the `PaymentTransfer` object.

```
    protected function mapSalesPaymentEntity(PaymentTransfer $paymentTransfer, $idSalesOrder)
    {
        $paymentMethodTypeEntity = parent::mapSalesPaymentEntity($paymentTransfer, $idSalesOrder);

        $salesPaymentEntity->setCustomPaymentId($paymentTransfer->getCustomPaymentId());

        return $salesPaymentEntity;
    }
```